# if the value exist retrieve last row of this value

Tags: vba, excel

I want vba code to look for specific ranges of data if these data exist in main sheet then retrieve last row of data that mean based on conditions.  For example(there are 3 row with "dler"  I want to compare dler with three rows of second sheet if all exist retrieve the row of dler) that mean compare name with other rows and so on... The picture is two sheets the first one is (main sheet) and the second one is the table that the vba work on it to find data in (main sheet) I have this code but I don't know how change it to work with dynamic records.

[Main and Search Worksheet Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoPC5.jpg)

```
Sub Matching_name()
    Dim a_name As String, i As Long, j As Long, Last_Row As Long

    For i = Last_Row To 2 Step -1
        a_name = Cells(i, "B").Value
        If City = "dler" Then
            'Set the range destination, Range(“A2”), depending on which
            'range you want in Sheets(“Remaining”)
            Rows(i).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Remaining").Range("A1")
            Exit For
        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: what you're trying to achieve. And may be examples of input and output data, too.

Comment: search with this condition (dler--wakil--30days)if exist copy last rowof these conditional data to remaining table then ,,(dler--wakil--30days Double)then (dler--wakil--30days family)then (dler--wakil--100 hours)(dler--wakil--40 hours) after that (dler--bazar--30days) ........ and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will copy the last matching rows

```
Sub Matching_name()

Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, Last_Row As Long, temp As Long
Dim a_name As String, s_type As String, c_type As String

temp = 1
Last_Row = 6

For i = 2 To Last_Row
    Worksheets("Main Sheet").Activate
    a_name = Cells(i, 2).Value
    s_type = Cells(i, 5).Value
    c_type = Cells(i, 6).Value

    Worksheets("Search Sheet").Activate
    For j = 1 To 3
        If Cells(j, 1).Value = a_name And Cells(j, 2).Value = s_type And Cells(j, 3).Value = c_type Then
            Worksheets("Main Sheet").Activate
            Rows(i & ":" & i).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Worksheets("Remaining").Activate
            Rows(temp & ":" & temp).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            temp = temp + 1
        End If
    Next j
Next i

Worksheets("Remaining").Activate
For x = temp To 1 Step -1
    y = 1
    While y <= temp
        If Cells(y, 2).Value = Cells(x, 2).Value And x <> y Then
            Rows(y & ":" & y).Delete
            y = y - 1
            temp = temp - 1
        End If
        y = y + 1
    Wend
Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: it's retrieve only one record and not last record of the specific condition(if there are many rows with the same record i want it to copy last record)....what about other names (pashew, zana) with same conditions?thanks in advance

Comment: see my edited answer above. In you main sheet in row 5 if the dler sale_type was wakil and card_type was 30 Days, then 'remaining' sheet will have only 5th row data (No = 4) from 'main sheet' and not the 2 row (No = 2)

Comment: the code must work like this(first cache dler if exist search for "wakil , ...,..." if one of theme exist then search for"30 Days ,...,...")if all condition match then copy last row of matching data....after that (cache dler if exist search for "wakil , ....,..." if one of theme exist then search for 30 Days Double) and so on for all conditions in search sheet

Comment: as per your screenshot of 'main sheet' and 'search sheet' could you tell me what should be the data in 'remaning' sheet

Comment: last row of results of  conditional  (dler,1/1/2016,wakil,30days,250dler,1/1/2016,wakil,30days,300) i want to copy last row that mean the one with 300 not 250

Comment: let us ignore the second condition we want only (name and card type)

Comment: Did you try the current edited answer, because if i run for the data (1,dler,1/1/2016,wakil,30days,250) & (2,dler,1/1/2016,wakil,30days,300) i am getting the one with 300 and not 250

Comment: it's working perfect but there is only one record what about all others i want it work with the same way with all records in main data sheet

Comment: i have written the code for 5 records in main sheet and 3 records in search sheet. change the 'Last_Row =  6' to your desired value according to the records in your main sheet and change 'For j = 1 To 3' according to the data in search sheet

Comment: Thanks For Genius Answer